# Is it possible to have filter of only guassian blur?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects, blur

I want to be able to save a file of my logo, with a guassian blur filter under it, that blurs any background you choose to place it on. The text of the logo is within a rectangle and it's transparent so a blurred effect is necessary for images with lots of detail otherwise the text on the logo is hard to read.

A filter of guassian blur would be very helpful because you otherwise have to apply guassian blur on a small part of every image you place the logo on which isn't something i think the association (which is driven by volonteers) could handle.

It's not vital to the visuall identity, i could think of other ideas for external communication involving photography, or express that you must only use it on backgrounds without a lot of detail, but it would be really great if it's possible to do.

Comment: Its possible but not practical, see it only ever works in the authoring application but you can not save it part of say a  png and thus it can not do so on a web page irrespective of background. Also if you do it in illustrator it wont react with photoshop and vice versa.

Comment: Could you clarify, do you want to save *an image file* (as in JPG/PNG/whatever) that acts as a filter for anything underneath that image? Or are you talking about something to use specifically in Photoshop/Illustrator etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but as already hinted in comments, a general type photo file such as PNG, has no way to cause  its background to be blurred or other complex filtering. A photo can only  hide  the background on which the photo is placed. Hiding can be only partial, if the photo has  some transparency. I have no way to create a PNG which makes  something blurred on your document in case you embed my PNG.

Of course some theoretical possiblities exist:

- to hide an ingenious piece of malware into my PNG
- you have a specially programmed platform that recognizes something in my PNG and that's the signal to blur the area beneath  my PNG

Both methods unfortunately are impractical, because I can't force you to use a platform which is infectable by malware or preprogrammed to do the wanted blurring.

Comment: The second option was done by [Adobe Fireworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Fireworks). They 'hid' all of the editable information in PNG metadata. It was horrible.

Comment: Another example would be SVG with a stylesheet could do this on a webpage but again not much use elsewhere. @PieBie

Comment: And given that there is no reason to execute a PNG in the first place, option 1 would be incredibly difficult. And even if you succeed, it only works if the loophole is fixed.